# How to skip header in Sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

How can i sqoop export skipping the header of my csv from the HDFS to MSSQL?
I've tried to researched about this, but i can't find any answer. So this is the problem im having right now.
If my csv have header some of my data are not saved, I think it is skipping some of the rows. Then, when i made my table data type to varchar, the header got also saved, that's why i tried to delete the header and sqoop it again, it saved my data to my table without any problem.

The csv files im getting always have a header that's why i'm looking a setting in sqoop to skip the csv header.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send everything to a staging table and use call stored_procedure. In that stored procedure, you can filter this record before inserting into final table. I too did not find any direct property option. Otherwise the best way is to manipulate the file and then do sqoop. You are already aware about this process.

Answer (score 0):

--first ~ remove Header in HDFS, then try below properties
==> sed -i 1d your_File_Name.csv

--Verify count
select count(*) from stg_card_transactions;

--Remove Dups from Stg Table
alter ignore table stg_card_transactions
add unique index idx_card_txns (card_id,transaction_dt);

--Verify no dups
select card_id,transaction_dt,count(*) from stg_card_transactions group by card_id,transaction_dt having count(*) >1;

--Dropping index used for removing dups
alter table stg_card_transactions drop index idx_card_txns;

--Loading main table
insert into card_transactions
select card_id,member_id,amount,postcode,pos_id,STR_TO_DATE(transaction_dt,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'),status from stg_card_transactions;
commit;

--Verify the count
select count(*) from card_transactions;